# Google places api - adding additional details after place added

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have just integrated with Google maps so that our clients can add their Business to Google Places via a CRM.

The API is working great, but where can our clients view their listing to add additional info?

With the API it seems like we can only add:
Location
Accuracy
Type
Name

Is there a way to add more information via the API? i.e. address, website, contact numbers, (maybe even products for sale etc?)

If anyone could guide me in the right direction it would be hugely appreciated.